# Codeigniter/Datamapper "where_related" causing too many queries

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I have a many-to-many mapping between `profiles` and `categories`.   This query:

```
$profiles = new Profile();  
$profiles->where('foobar_flag',1);
$profiles->where_related($category);
$profiles->get();
```

Is taking almost 30 seconds to run, with about 1000 entries in that profiles table.  There is also a category table, and a profiles_categories table.  I end up with a staggering 4000 queries per execution.

How do I make this faster?

Comment: We may need to see more code than that. Can you at least isolate *some* of the queries, or does this *only* happen using the `where_related()` line? Are you doing anything in the `__construct()` of your models? How is `$category` created? How many results do you expect, 1000?

Comment: where_related increases the number of queries by 10.7x, somehow.  The construct methods are essentially empty.  $category is just iterated in an array of categories.

Comment: You might be better off creating an array from `$category` ids and doing a `where_in()` on the join table. I don't want to add that as an answer because you shouldn't have to do stuff like that with an ORM, but I don't know if this is a shortcoming of Datamapper or not.

Comment: I was wondering if that was possible.

Comment: I'd say it's a good idea to get the queries down, but there might be a more appropriate "DM" way to do it. I side-step Datamapper sometimes for certain things and just use Active Record, but it sucks having to do it, like hard-coding or otherwise manually constructing the name of the join table for an AR query.

Comment: Datamapper has many `where_related` methods ( http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html ) that might optimize this a bit, but it's tough to say what might help. Could you offer more info? Maybe run a `$profiles->check_last_query()` and let us see the actual query - or put up a test page with `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` and give us the link.

Comment: Please revise your question, you show **ZERO code**, not a constructive question, marked for **CLOSE**.

Comment: Add more code, and example data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unhappy with a function in datamapper, either find a simplified way of doing it as your active record query might just be too costly as you say.

Always run your profiler:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

This will give you a true idea of what is being done behind the scenes.  Optimize from there on.  Otherwise we need more code to go on here to give relevant answers.